# Using timevis in R presentations

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, rpres

I'm trying to include an HTML widget created by `timevis` in an R presentation (.Rpres).

I'm using:

```
library(timevis)
data <- data.frame(id = 1:4,
   content = c("Item one", "Item two","Ranged item", "Item four"),
   start = c("2016-01-10", "2016-01-11","2016-01-20","2016-02-14 15:00:00"),
   end = c(NA, NA, "2016-02-04", NA))

timevis(data)
```

to create the widget.
The code runs and the widget appears in the plot area, and is also successfully integrated into HTML output from a knitted `Rmd` document.

However, in Rpres, the slide returns the error:
`Error in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the connection`.

It doesn't work in ioslides, but does in slidy.

How can I embed this (and other html widgets) in Rpres?

Thanks in advance!